# Cannot delete from mysql (file.size)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

First I inserted a new record into a database with a field file_size. It all works fine. Then I want to delete the record with a given name and size from the database. It works with name, but when I add AND statement it doesnt work.

```
$conn->query("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE '%{$t}' AND file_size = '$file_size'");
```

file_size is passed through $file_size= $_POST['size']; and it works correctly. The number in the database and the one passed is the same. I have no idea why the above doesnt work...at first I thought that maybe these are different data types and hence I am comparing string with integer, but in Javascript it shouldnt matter...Any advice would be greately appreciated.

Comment: You've outputted the query, executed it, and it worked?

Comment: You are doing a string comparisson, so a `var_dump()` of both variables (POST and the database row) should show you the exact differences.

Comment: I hope you're sanitizing `$file_size` or you're opening yourself to SQL injection

Comment: It works with name, but not deleting like the filesize is different. However when I check the values in database and echo the value of $file_size= $_POST['size'], these are the same numbers...

Comment: what type of coloum is *file_size* on mysql? what is the value of $file_size?

Comment: file_size is TEXT, I also tred Integer. $file_size is inserted as $_FILES['file']['size'] and then quried as (javascript) file.size, but both value are the same in the database...

Comment: You're showing php and sql. What does javascript have to do with it?

Comment: @jeroen I am not showing the entire application, the data is once taken as $_FILES['file']['size']  and once as file.size due to the library that I am using. Both values are the same in the database though, so it shouldnt matter.

Comment: Only a `var_dump()` will tell you. And I would take mysql's word over yours so no, they're most likely not the same.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe prepare request

```
$query=$conn->prepare("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE :like_param AND file_size = :filesize");
$query->excute(array(':like_param' => '%'.$t, ':filesize' => $file_size));
```